# Wireless network connection dialog keeps popping up

Tags: wireless

This is a network I once tried to connect to by mistake in the past. Now every few minutes the connect window keeps popping up and it is really annoying. How can I solve this? Thanks and please move this to the appropriate forum if that's not here.

Answer (score 1):

You've set that old wireless connection to "Connect automatically". To fix this:

1. LClick and hold on Network Manager (the radar screen icon in the top row).
2. Scroll down to "**Edit connections**" and select that.
3. Click on the "**Wireless**" tab.
4. Select the old, unwanted connection, and click "**Delete**" or "**Edit**" and uncheck "**Connect automatically**".[image]